# Show final time in Alert Dialog after 10 button clicks

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Right now I have my app set to show an alert dialog after 10 button clicks as well as stop the timer. I cannot figure out how to display the final time the timer stops on in the alert dialog. I want to make an alert dialog that displays that the game is over and also displays the players final time. Any idea how I would do this? Please help if you can.

JAVA CODE:

```
package com.example.thirtytapgametest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AnalogClock;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int mCount = 0;

private ImageButton startbutton;

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    startbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);       
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) { 
            if (mCount ==0) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            }

            mCount++;
            countTextView.setText("Taps: " + mCount);
            if(mCount == 10) {
                view.setEnabled(false);
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new                         AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Congratulations!")
                    .setMessage((R.id.timerValue))
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.play_again), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {   

                            dialog.cancel();}})
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.levels_menu), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();}});           

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }           
    });

}


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        updatedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("Time: " + "" + mins + ":"
                +String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                +String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

    };


}
```

XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/thirty_tap_game_background">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_play_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/timerVal" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
        android:text="@string/countVal" 
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the set message method in your AlertDialog builder.

```
.setTitle("Congratulations!")
.setMessage("Your time was: " + updatedTime)
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

Comment: This works well, but the number in my AlertDialog does not appear as a timer value. Instead it just appears as a whole number. For example the time could be 2:435 seconds, but in the AlertDialog it appears as 2435. Any way to correct this in the AlertDialog to appear correctly?

Comment: It shows up as a number because SystemClock.uptimeMillis() represents it as such. To convert it, simply use the method you are using for your TextView.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how to convert the time. I do not fully understand what you are telling me to do. If you could give an example to show me what you are talking about that would be great.  @Aaron

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
int i =0;   // declare this globally.

btn.setonclicklistener(new onClicklistener
    onclick(View v){
    i++;
    if(i==10){
        // show alert dialog 
    }
    else{
        // to do your stub here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

and your code shows you using :

```
.setMessage((R.id.timerValue))
```

R.id.viewName refers to the hex id of the resource .Using this will not set the value that is contained in the textView.
you could try:

```
.setMessage(((TextView)R.id.timerValue).getText().toString())
```

or you could declare the text view earlier and call TextView.getText().toString() while creating the dialog.